# Cannot slide to last items

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

My aim is to get a similar swiping-tabs-experience like in native android.
The WhatsApp tabs at the start screen are a good example for my aim.

So I decided to use http://idangero.us/swiper.
My config looks like:

```
// This works -> but I dont want centered slides
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
    centeredSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto'
});

// This will not work -> I can only slide the first elements but I cannot slide to the last ones
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
    slidesPerView: 'auto'
});
```

Here is a screenshot of my problem (I have 10 divs. Active slide has bg-color red.):

[image]

So I can only slide until slide 7. Trying to slide further does not work.

[image]

Is my aim possible with the selected swiper plugin?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `slidesOffsetBefore` see documentation [here](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WK1f0n8VtPY)

Comment: Can you provide example code? I tried it out but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just add right margin to the last swiper slide

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.slider .swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
})
```

```css
.slider .swiper-slide {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
}

.slider .swiper-slide:last-child {
    margin-right: calc(100% - (100% / 3));
}

.slider .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@6.0.4/swiper-bundle.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@6.0.4/swiper-bundle.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```